# How to get the relative path segment for Apache Camel File2

Tags: apache-camel

I'm trying to build a file based integration where files are dumped in one of the subdirectories of a main directory for processing. I need to get the name of the sub-directory to know which client the file is for. So if I have:

/uploads/foo/bar.txt

I need to process that file and know that it's for client "foo". I'm not sure how to get that part and set it as a header for the processor that processes the bar.txt file. I've got it picking up files and processing, now I need to add in this piece.

Anyone have ideas for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get most of this information in the header of the exchange. In your situation as you are consuming the file the following items are avlable:

- CamelFileName: Name of the consumed file as a relative file path with
  offset from the starting directory configured on the endpoint.
- CamelFileNameOnly: Only the file name (the name with no leading
  paths).
- CamelFileAbsolute: A boolean option specifying whether the consumed
  file denotes an absolute path or not. Should normally be false for
  relative paths. Absolute paths should normally not be used but we
  added to the move option to allow moving files to absolute paths. But
  can be used elsewhere as well.
- CamelFileAbsolutePath: The absolute path to the file. For relative
  files this path holds the  relative path instead.
- CamelFilePath: The file path. For relative files this is the starting       directory + the relative filename. For absolute files this is the absolute path.
- CamelFileRelativePath: The relative path.
- CamelFileParent: The parent path.
- CamelFileLength: A long value containing the file size.
- CamelFileLastModified: A Date value containing the last modified
  timestamp of the file.

You can query these headers for the information you are looking for using the following example as guidelines:

```
<log message ="${header.CamelFileAbsolutePath}"/>
```

See [the file component documents](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html) at the Camel website for more details.